# wait until label gets displayed

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, tcltk

so in my Tcl/Tk application I have a label with a text-variable:

```
    label .mylabel -textvariable statustext -relief sunken -anchor w
```

and I can change the content of the label just fine by using something like `set statustext "sponatenous error"`.

Unfortunately, sometimes the update of this variable is followed by some "heavy processing" that stalls the GUI for some time (e.g. downloading a file from the internet).

```
set statustext "downloading from $url"
download $url
```

Since the event-queue is blocked (at least, that's what I guess), the GUI does not get any refreshes and the `label` does not show my latest message.

Is there a way to force-update the label text (preferrably via a textvariable) before starting my "heavy process"?

Comment: I wonder whether it would be possible to the download in the background somehow? I/O-bound processing is usually easy to convert to being done with event-based code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **do `update idletasks` before your heavy processing,** the actual GUI update code will run. Tk works that way because *actual* GUI drawing is quite expensive and this allows it to bunch updates efficiently. It's a *very* clever piece of design that's made Tk GUIs seem super fast for over 25 years.

In some cases, a full `update` is necessary — which can cause all sorts of problems with reentrancy of event handling — but updating a label can usually be done with the cheaper and less troublesome variant. That's *especially* true if your change doesn't alter the actual size of the label (which depends on how you're handling the geometry management of the whole containing toplevel, which is a huge topic). As a hint, it's usually best if your GUI doesn't resize itself when you alter a label's text dynamically; otherwise, that can be a bit disorienting to the user.